# Contact Motion Analysis (CMA)

Tags: sensors, aerospace-engineering

In this solution [Helicoptor Fire Control System](https://www.drdo.gov.in/drdo/English/index.jsp?pg=helicoptor-fire-control-system.jsp)

CMA is used. For motion analysis we use computer vision and image processing. But what is special about CMA.

Comment: You will receive much more response if you add information or links explaining what CMW means here.

Comment: This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (even if it isn't homework). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you read about CMA so far? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick skim of a few monographs and book excerpts (which, by the way, are easily found via web search -- something worth doing before posting a wide-open question), it appears that CMA is an active system - sonar or radar, for example, which provides a wealth of information on object range, size, and motion.  Further, any active system can operate regardless of local illumination, as opposed to a vision system which shuts down after sunset (roughly speaking).